# asmack android ,unable to transfer file

Tags: android, exception, smack

I am unable to transfer file using a smack, I am using android emulator on one side and spark on the other. When I do transfer the application force closes with the following error messages and a notification of file transfer request, after accepting the file, there was an error transfering the file.error log is pasted below.

I searched different solution and one of them says:

> First, you have to copy a smack.properties to you android emulator.
>   You can get smack.properties at the original SMACK API site.
>
> http://www.igniterealtime.org/downloads/source.jsp

I opened the site and downloaded the source code of smack but unable to find `smack.properties` anywhere.
1st choice closed.

Second solution proposed was to change the implementation of `discoverLocalIP()` in `org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.Socks5TransferNegotiator.discoverLocalIP()` which I am unable to find.

How can i transfer file?

---

```
WARN/dalvikvm(4994): threadid=25: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4994): Uncaught handler: thread File Transfer jsi_8875615847496033183 exiting due to uncaught exception
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4994): java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jivesoftware.smack.util.PacketParserUtils$2
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4994):     at org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.FileTransferNegotiator.negotiateOutgoingTransfer(FileTransferNegotiator.java:401)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4994):     at org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.OutgoingFileTransfer.negotiateStream(OutgoingFileTransfer.java:359)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4994):     at org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.OutgoingFileTransfer.access$100(OutgoingFileTransfer.java:35)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4994):     at org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.OutgoingFileTransfer$2.run(OutgoingFileTransfer.java:214)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4994):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The config files are under

```
resources/META-INF/
```

The ones you will need are

```
smack-config.xml
smack.providers
```

Your specific error is caused by the fact that the **ProviderManager** has not been configured with the **smack.providers** file.  This results in the incoming packets being read into the default **PacketExtension** instead of the one configured for the specific stanza type.

If you are using asmack, I would think that would be handled already.  If regular Smack, you will have to configure the ProviderManager to read the file from the right location.

I think you can do this by extending **ProviderManager** and overriding the *initialize()* method.  Basically copy the existing one but specify the android resource directory instead of the META-INF one.  There is already a Jira task against this to make the directory configurable, but it isn't resolved yet.

In addition, there was a bug in file transfer that was fixed in the latest version (3.2.1).

Comment: I am coding for android so i dont think smack will work for me. I cannot extend the ProviderManager class because its constructor is set to private. the issue is not yet handled in asmack. You are right about the problem but can you tell me the way to solve the problem?  One solution is to take the smack source code apply all the patches given for android.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the constructor at the bottom.  Funny that it was put there since the initialize method (the one you want to change) is marked protected and the class wasn't marked final.  Looks like you will have to alter the code until this task is completed http://issues.igniterealtime.org/browse/SMACK-286

Comment: Would this not work with a proper call to ProviderManager.addExtensionProvider ?

Comment: @ozmank How did you solve this issue ? Please do share as i am facing the same

Answer (score 2):

[@hunt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/405383/hunt) Create the following function to configure provider mager and call it before the file is sent.

```
public void configureProviderManager() {
    ProviderManager pm = ProviderManager.getInstance();

    // The order is the same as in the smack.providers file

    //  Private Data Storage
    pm.addIQProvider("query","jabber:iq:private", new PrivateDataManager.PrivateDataIQProvider());
    //  Time
    try {
        pm.addIQProvider("query","jabber:iq:time", Class.forName("org.jivesoftware.smackx.packet.Time"));
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("Can't load class for org.jivesoftware.smackx.packet.Time");
    }

    //  Roster Exchange
    pm.addExtensionProvider("x","jabber:x:roster", new RosterExchangeProvider());
    //  Message Events
    pm.addExtensionProvider("x","jabber:x:event", new MessageEventProvider());
    //  Chat State
    pm.addExtensionProvider("active","http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates", new ChatStateExtension.Provider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("composing","http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates", new ChatStateExtension.Provider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("paused","http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates", new ChatStateExtension.Provider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("inactive","http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates", new ChatStateExtension.Provider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("gone","http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates", new ChatStateExtension.Provider());

    //  XHTML
    pm.addExtensionProvider("html","http://jabber.org/protocol/xhtml-im", new XHTMLExtensionProvider());

    //  Group Chat Invitations
    pm.addExtensionProvider("x","jabber:x:conference", new GroupChatInvitation.Provider());
    //  Service Discovery # Items
    pm.addIQProvider("query","http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items", new DiscoverItemsProvider());
    //  Service Discovery # Info
    pm.addIQProvider("query","http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info", new DiscoverInfoProvider());
    //  Data Forms
    pm.addExtensionProvider("x","jabber:x:data", new DataFormProvider());
    //  MUC User
    pm.addExtensionProvider("x","http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user", new MUCUserProvider());
    //  MUC Admin
    pm.addIQProvider("query","http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin", new MUCAdminProvider());
    //  MUC Owner
    pm.addIQProvider("query","http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#owner", new MUCOwnerProvider());
    //  Delayed Delivery
    pm.addExtensionProvider("x","jabber:x:delay", new DelayInformationProvider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("delay", "urn:xmpp:delay", new DelayInformationProvider());
    //  Version
    try {
        pm.addIQProvider("query","jabber:iq:version", Class.forName("org.jivesoftware.smackx.packet.Version"));
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("Can't load class for org.jivesoftware.smackx.packet.Version");
    }
    //  VCard
    pm.addIQProvider("vCard","vcard-temp", new VCardProvider());
    //  Offline Message Requests
    pm.addIQProvider("offline","http://jabber.org/protocol/offline", new OfflineMessageRequest.Provider());
    //  Offline Message Indicator
    pm.addExtensionProvider("offline","http://jabber.org/protocol/offline", new OfflineMessageInfo.Provider());
    //  Last Activity
    pm.addIQProvider("query","jabber:iq:last", new LastActivity.Provider());
    //  User Search
    pm.addIQProvider("query","jabber:iq:search", new UserSearch.Provider());
    //  SharedGroupsInfo
    pm.addIQProvider("sharedgroup","http://www.jivesoftware.org/protocol/sharedgroup", new SharedGroupsInfo.Provider());

    //  JEP-33: Extended Stanza Addressing
    pm.addExtensionProvider("addresses","http://jabber.org/protocol/address", new MultipleAddressesProvider());

    //   FileTransfer
    pm.addIQProvider("si","http://jabber.org/protocol/si", new StreamInitiationProvider());
    pm.addIQProvider("query","http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams", new BytestreamsProvider());
    pm.addIQProvider("open","http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb", new OpenIQProvider());
    pm.addIQProvider("data","http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb", new DataPacketProvider());
    pm.addIQProvider("close","http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb", new CloseIQProvider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("data","http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb", new DataPacketProvider());

    //  Privacy
    pm.addIQProvider("query","jabber:iq:privacy", new PrivacyProvider());

    // SHIM
    pm.addExtensionProvider("headers", "http://jabber.org/protocol/shim", new HeadersProvider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("header", "http://jabber.org/protocol/shim", new HeaderProvider());

    // PubSub
    pm.addIQProvider("pubsub", "http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub", new PubSubProvider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("create", "http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub", new SimpleNodeProvider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("items", "http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub", new ItemsProvider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("item", "http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub", new ItemProvider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("subscriptions", "http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub", new SubscriptionsProvider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("subscription", "http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub", new SubscriptionProvider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("affiliations", "http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub", new AffiliationsProvider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("affiliation", "http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub", new AffiliationProvider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("options", "http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub", new FormNodeProvider());
    // PubSub owner
    pm.addIQProvider("pubsub", "http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#owner", new PubSubProvider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("configure", "http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#owner", new FormNodeProvider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("default", "http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#owner", new FormNodeProvider());
    // PubSub event
    pm.addExtensionProvider("event", "http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#event", new EventProvider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("configuration", "http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#event", new ConfigEventProvider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("delete", "http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#event", new SimpleNodeProvider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("options", "http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#event", new FormNodeProvider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("items", "http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#event", new ItemsProvider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("item", "http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#event", new ItemProvider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("retract", "http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#event", new RetractEventProvider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("purge", "http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#event", new SimpleNodeProvider());

    // Nick Exchange
    pm.addExtensionProvider("nick", "http://jabber.org/protocol/nick", new Nick.Provider());

    // Attention
    pm.addExtensionProvider("attention", "urn:xmpp:attention:0", new AttentionExtension.Provider());

}
```

Comment: This is not out of context. The answer just lacks some explanation why this is needed.